# Background image not loading

Tags: html, css

I am new to html/css and I do not understand why my background image is not showing up. This is part of a simple test CSS sheet and HTML code for a simple site. I am trying to add a background-image and I have done this once and it worked and I do not know why it does not work now.

```
.timeline{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-flex;
    background-image:url("img/back.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Is it possible your image file path is incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried `url("https://example.com/full/path/to/img/back.jpg")`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes I have tried giving the full

Comment: Repeat is default for background so omit it, position 0 0 is also default so you can omit it. Demo : http://output.jsbin.com/vezakev

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 3):

Your rule is wrong. You are trying to set `background-image`, `background-position` and other rules, but rule name is only `background-image`.

Use `background` instead of `background-image`

Comment: Backgrounds have reasonable defaults.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol OP tries to set everything at once, but uses wrong rule name.

Comment: Oh yes. How did I miss that? XD

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for background-image is incorrect

You need to use `background-repeat: repeat;` for repeat. Here is doc [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

```
.timeline{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-image:url("img/back.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: He states the image is not showing up, not that it is not repeating. Or am I not understanding the question here?

Comment: @Vandal the css syntax is for `background-image` is wrong , thats why its not showing

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this code

```
display:inline-flex;
```

to this code

```
display:flex;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Asuming your file path is correct.

```
.timeline{
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
display: inline-flex;
```

**background-image: url(img/back.jpg);**}

Answer (score 0):

```
.timeline{
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-image:url("./img/back.jpg");

}
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation of your solution would improve the quality of this answer.